# How to get last N records after JOIN in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables in mysql -
Table 1: **notes**

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| note_id       | varchar(25) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| topic         | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| note_html     | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| note_markdown | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| access_type   | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date          | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time          | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2: **notes_subject**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| note_id      | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subject_name | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 3: **notes_tag**

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| note_id  | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_name | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and suppose the content stored in **notes** table as (I am leaving some attributes of this tables like note_html, note_markdown because it has large data) -

```
+----+---------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+------------+----------+
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  6 |       1 | e657ZxsYaWR2 | 2020-08-06 | 10:43:08 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
+----+---------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

and suppose the content stored in **notes_subject** table as -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |
|  6 |       1 | e657ZxsYaWR2 | computer     |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

and suppose the content stored in **notes_tag** table as -

```
+-----+---------+--------------+--------------+
| id  | user_id | note_id      | tag_name     |
+-----+---------+--------------+--------------+
|  7  |       1 | e657ZxsYaWR2 |  definition  |
|  70 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer fan |
|  71 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ |  clean       |
| 250 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | sql          |
| 251 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | mysql        |
| 252 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup |  select      |
| 253 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup |  ASC         |
| 254 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup |  DESC        |
| 257 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | cn           |
| 258 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn |  IPV4        |
| 261 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | AND          |
| 262 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF |  NAND        |
+-----+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

I used `JOIN` with these three tables -

```
SELECT N.id, N.user_id, N.note_id, S.subject_name, T.tag_name, N.date, N.time 
from notes AS N 
JOIN notes_subject AS S ON N.user_id = 2 
  AND N.user_id = S.user_id 
  AND N.note_id = S.note_id 
JOIN notes_tag AS T ON N.user_id = T.user_id 
  AND N.note_id = T.note_id 
ORDER BY N.date DESC
LIMIT 3
```

and it fetched -
**Result 1 :**

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name | tag_name | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           | cn       | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |  IPV4    | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          | AND      | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

and If I run above query without `LIMIT`, it fetched -
**Result 2 :**

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name | tag_name     | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           | cn           | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |  IPV4        | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          | AND          | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          |  NAND        | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     | computer fan | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     |  clean       | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | sql          | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | mysql        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  select      | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  ASC         | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  DESC        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

In the **Result 1 :** there are three rows of IDs (7,7,8) which are last inserted.  But result must be like -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name | tag_name     | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           | cn           | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |  IPV4        | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          | AND          | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          |  NAND        | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     | computer fan | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     |  clean       | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

The result must be included with all the tag_name of a particular ID.

Comment: How do you consider unique combination? id + user_id + subject_name + tag_name?

Comment: What is the logic for retaining only these three id values?  Then, within each id group, what is the logic for which records to retain?

Comment: @tcadidot0 There is one more attribute named as `note_id`. whenever a user wants to save a new note she/he has to give `subject_name, topic_name , tags, note_markdown` and on saving the note there will create a unique *note_id*  for that note. So tag_name must be unique  for each each note_id

Comment: I have updated my question by adding `note_id` attribute in sql result

Comment: But you still haven't explained fully your logic.

Comment: Please see the @Barmar answer it worked for me. It gives the last three records with the duplicate IDs too–

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question description in detail, please tell me again if you still can't able to understand my question.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to say they are answered, click on the check mark beside the answer. [ask] [help] [meta.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the limit in a subquery that fetches the 3 latest notes before joining.

```
SELECT N.id, N.user_id, N.note_id, S.subject_name, T.tag_name, N.date, N.time 
from (SELECT *
      FROM notes
      WHERE user_id = 2
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 3) AS N 
JOIN notes_subject AS S ON N.user_id = S.user_id 
                       AND N.note_id = S.note_id 
JOIN notes_tag AS T ON N.user_id = T.user_id 
                   AND N.note_id = T.note_id
```

Comment: It gives an error `Unknown column 'N.date' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Fixed it. There's no need for the alias inside the subquery.

Comment: Thanks It **worked**, you helped me a lot , I will have to master in SQL.

Comment: Please check why your query is not working - I have explained [here](https://justpaste.it/7t2s8)

Comment: `WHERE user_id = 2` should be in the subquery.

Comment: nope still not working, please see the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356880/get-last-n-records-after-join-in-sql) question which i asked today. (and please read question description again in my today asked question)