# Get last N records after JOIN in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am creating a website for myself where I can create **notes** on any subjects.
For creating a note I have to give subject name, topic, tags, note content.
Whenever I press save button to save my new note it will store all the information in MYSQL DB in given bellow three tables. There is also a unique note_id for each note.
I can give **multiple tag** for a single note so one tag will store in a single row, 2nd tag will store in another row and so on.. in `notes_tag table`.

There are three tables in MYSQL DB -

1. notes
2. notes_subject
3. notes_tag

So If I want to fetch all notes of the **user_id =2** with date and time in descending order (`STACK ORDER`), I run given below query -

```
SELECT N.id,N.user_id,N.note_id ,S.subject_name,T.tag_name,N.date, N.time from notes AS N 
JOIN notes_subject AS S ON N.user_id = 2  
AND N.user_id = S.user_id 
AND N.note_id = S.note_id 
JOIN notes_tag AS T ON N.user_id = T.user_id 
AND N.note_id = T.note_id 
ORDER BY N.date DESC, time DESC;
```

and It fetched -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name | tag_name     | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 28 |       2 | DFbw8bOhVvuY | Logo         | logo         | 2020-08-11 | 12:21:09 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          | AND          | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          |  NAND        | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           | cn           | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |  IPV4        | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
| 25 |       2 | mpngBCarbHuu | new norw     | kjk45        | 2020-08-10 | 06:13:48 |
| 24 |       2 | 7zdqslgj2AFd | subject1     | tag1         | 2020-08-10 | 06:12:37 |
| 23 |       2 | LaHLcnPotDat | subject2     | l;k          | 2020-08-10 | 06:10:20 |
| 22 |       2 | FgGqsVFrdjSH | subject3     | JGH          | 2020-08-10 | 06:09:02 |
| 21 |       2 | rrsz6eIh1sny | K            | lkj          | 2020-08-10 | 06:07:56 |
| 20 |       2 | NNLhTXSqZcbs | subject5     | lkj          | 2020-08-10 | 06:02:47 |
| 19 |       2 | nOYQunMfi09p | subject16    | j            | 2020-08-10 | 06:02:28 |
| 18 |       2 | GYI2B8A5XWBP | subject13    | lk           | 2020-08-10 | 06:01:58 |
| 16 |       2 | 3mFvXIt5KVx8 | subject11    | kkklk        | 2020-08-10 | 06:00:18 |
| 15 |       2 | jisgFUdh1jAu | subject15    | ;lksd        | 2020-08-10 | 05:52:41 |
| 14 |       2 | Hnmv4AXvgn0m | subject10    | lksd         | 2020-08-10 | 05:51:50 |
| 13 |       2 | JgsebjXpR7w3 | subject9     | lkals        | 2020-08-10 | 05:50:53 |
| 12 |       2 | EvCAPWsntTIO | subject8     | lklas        | 2020-08-10 | 05:48:12 |
| 11 |       2 | 86ZTfX641bCA | subject7     | alsk         | 2020-08-10 | 05:47:14 |
| 10 |       2 | ZqlvwNvzA7fn | subject6     | lkjas        | 2020-08-10 | 05:44:50 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     | computer fan | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     |  clean       | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  DESC        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  ASC         | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  select      | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | mysql        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | sql          | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
27 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Note :** There are two more attributes 'note_html', 'note_markdown' which contains my note content. I haven't include both attribute in result of SQL query due to its large data.
But If I want **last 3** or **last N** inserted notes of the user_id=2 . What should be the query ?

The result of last 3 inserted notes of user_id=2 must be like -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | note_id      | subject_name | tag_name     | date       | time     |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 28 |       2 | DFbw8bOhVvuY | Logo         | logo         | 2020-08-11 | 12:21:09 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          | AND          | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  8 |       2 | BW2aMLYN8CIF | DLD          |  NAND        | 2020-08-10 | 11:24:35 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           | cn           | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
|  7 |       2 | ARJuTcItPgbn | CN           |  IPV4        | 2020-08-10 | 11:19:11 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

OR If I want first 2 inserted notes of user_id=2, result must be -

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | sql          | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          | mysql        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  select      | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  ASC         | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  3 |       2 | RfYg3u59Ytup | SQL          |  DESC        | 2020-08-06 | 12:50:51 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     |  clean       | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
|  1 |       2 | nVf0It70bnjQ | computer     | computer fan | 2020-08-08 | 11:18:17 |
+----+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

Help here !

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I explained my problem in brief so that on one can get confuse about what do I want as a result. As this is an SQL question, any user can get different meaning if the question description is not clear and simple. By the way I accepted your *VOTE*.

Comment: I refer you again to the accepted answer at the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to select the most recent notes, and then `JOIN`:

```
select N.id, N.user_id, N.note_id, S.subject_name, T.tag_name, N.date, N.time
from (select N.*
      from notes N
      where N.user_id = 2
      order by N.date desc, N.time DESC
      limit 3
     ) N join
     notes_subject S  
     on N.user_id = S.user_id and
        N.note_id = S.note_id join
     notes_tag T 
     on N.user_id = T.user_id and
        N.note_id = T.note_id 
order by N.date DESC, N.time DESC;
```

I am guessing that you want the most recent notes, even if the other tables do not match.  For this, use `left join`s:

```
select N.id, N.user_id, N.note_id, S.subject_name, T.tag_name, N.date, N.time
from (select N.*
      from notes N
      where N.user_id = 2
      order by N.date desc, N.time DESC
      limit 3
     ) N left join
     notes_subject S  
     on N.user_id = S.user_id and
        N.note_id = S.note_id left join
     notes_tag T 
     on N.user_id = T.user_id and
        N.note_id = T.note_id 
order by N.date desc, N.time desc;
```

If you want only notes that match both tables, use `dense_rank()`:

```
select N.*
from (select N.id, N.user_id, N.note_id, S.subject_name, T.tag_name, N.date, N.time,
             dense_rank() over (order by N.date desc, N.time desc, n.id) as seqnum
      from notes N join
           notes_subject S  
           on N.user_id = S.user_id and
              N.note_id = S.note_id join
           notes_tag T 
           on N.user_id = T.user_id and
              N.note_id = T.note_id 
      ) N
where seqnum <= 3
order by N.date desc, N.time desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It worked for LIMIT 3 to get last three notes. I am running your query with the LIMIT 4 to get last four notes. It is returning same result as LIMIT 3 returned. What's problem ? Also same result with the LIMIT 5, but when I use LIMIT 6 then it returned last 4 notes.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal . . . My guess is that there is no match in the other tables.  Use `left join`s.

Comment: Yes you are right data was deleted from `notes_subject` and `notes_tag` table during development., Now it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to group by note_id and GROUP_CONCAT the tags, you can break them out later on the frontend with JavaScript (assuming you use JS on the front-end). You can configure the separator as well.

To reverse you can flip the ORDER BY from DESC to ASC and put any number after TOP.

[MYSQL GROUP CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT TOP 3
    N.id,N.user_id,N.note_id ,S.subject_name, GROUP_CONCAT(T.tag_name),N.date, N.time from notes AS N 
JOIN notes_subject AS S ON N.user_id = 2  
    AND N.user_id = S.user_id 
    AND N.note_id = S.note_id 
JOIN notes_tag AS T ON N.user_id = T.user_id 
    AND N.note_id = T.note_id 
GROUP BY note_id
    ORDER BY N.date DESC, time DESC;
```